# Show the Statistic is Complete

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a random sample $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ of the Uniform Distribution on the Interval $[-\phi,\phi]$

I'm wondering how I can show that the Statistic $$ T(\mathbf{Y}) = ( Y_{(1)} , Y_{(n)}) $$

is a Complete Statistic.

Thoughts so far :

the pdf of $T$ can be represented as $$ f(x,y) = n(n-1) \left(\frac{y-x}{2 \phi} \right)^{n-2} \frac{1}{4 \phi^2}  \; \; \; \; - \phi < x < y < \phi $$
The expectation of any measurable function  of $T$ can be represented as $$E[g(T)] = \int_{- \phi}^{\phi} \int_{x}^{\phi} g(x,y) f(x,y) \,dy\,dx $$

Setting this equal to $0$ however does not really let me continue very far. I cant deduce completeness

I can only guess that  I'm on the wrong track but I dont know how else to attempt this.

Comment: By the usual Order Statistics formula for the joint pdf of the min and max

Comment: There is a nice theorem describing how to derive a complete statistic if your random sample comes from an exponential family. Check page 288 of Casella and Berger.

Comment: @MoseWintner  , The Uniform Distribution with parameter determining its location is not an exponential distribution. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, my mistake. Briefly, a complete statistic is one where every function of it depends on the parameter. But in your case, since y-x is the range of the data raised to a power, if n is even and g is nonnegative, then g is 0 almost everywhere. If n is odd, pull off a power of y-x and try some stuff...

Comment: That still does not help though. what if g is neither strictly positive or negative  but a mix of the two ? Also you have not used phi at all in an answer like that.

Comment: @MoseWintner : It's not "where every function of it depends on the parameter", but rather "where the EXPECTED VALUE OF every function of it depends on the parameter". $\qquad$

Comment: $$\int_{-\varphi}^\varphi \int_x^\varphi g(x,y) n(n-1) \left(\frac{y-x}{2 \varphi} \right)^{n-2} \frac{1}{4 \varphi^2} \, dy\,dx$$
$$= \int_{-1}^1 \int_u^1 g(\varphi u,\varphi v) n(n-1) \left( \frac{v-u} 2 \right)^{n-2} \frac 1 4 \, dv\,du$$
$$= \frac{n(n-1)} {2^{n-2} \cdot 4} \int_{-1}^1 \int_u^1 g(\varphi u,\varphi v) (v-u)^{n-2} \, dv\,du.$$
Thus $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \int_u^1 g(\varphi u,\varphi v) (v-u)^{n-2} \, dv\,du$ remains equal to $0$ as $\varphi$ runs from $0$ to $\infty$.  The problem is to show that that implies $g$ is almost everywhere $0$.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHardy I don't think $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is complete. I've post my answer below.

Comment: $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is not even minimal sufficient. Keeping in mind that $|Y_i|\sim U(0,\phi)$, a [minimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1973864/321264) [complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699997/321264) sufficient statistic is instead $\max\{-Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}\}=\max_{1\le i\le n}|Y_i|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is not a complete statistic for $U(-\phi,\phi)$.

Proof:

**Method 1**

If $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is complete statistic, since $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is sufficient it is also a minimal sufficient statistic by Bahadur's theorem.

[We know](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354893/sufficient-statistics-for-uniform-theta-theta) that a minimal sufficient statistic for $U(-\phi,\phi)$ is $\max\{-Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}\}$. Since minimal sufficient statistics are one-to-one corresponded, there should be a one-to-one map between $\max\{-Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}\}$ and $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ if $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic. However, this is not possible since two different $(y_{(1)},y_{(n)})$ can have same $\max\{-y_{(1)},y_{(n)}\}$, e.g. when $(y_{(1)},y_{(n)})=(-1,0)$ or when $(y_{(1)},y_{(n)})=(0,1)$, $\max\{-y_{(1)},y_{(n)}\}$ are both $1$.

**Method 2**

We can write the p.d.f of $Y_{(n)}$ $$\delta_{Y_{(n)}}(y_n)=\frac{n}{(2\theta)^n}(y_n+\theta)^{n-1},y_n\in[-\phi,\phi]$$
and the p.d.f of $Y_{(1)}$ $$\delta_{Y_{(1)}}(y_1)=\frac{n}{(2\theta)^n}(\theta-y_1)^{n-1},y_1\in[-\phi,\phi].$$
Thus $$E_{\phi}[Y_{(n)}]=\frac{\phi(n-1)}{n+1}\text{ and }E_{\phi}[Y_{(1)}]=\frac{\phi(1-n)}{n+1}$$
This means if we let $g(x,z)=\frac{n+1}{n-1}z-\frac{n+1}{1-n}x$ we will get $$\mathbb{E}_{\phi}(g(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)}))=0,\forall\phi\in\mathbb{R}\text{ but } g\not\equiv0,$$
which means $(Y_{(1)},Y_{(n)})$ is not complete.

Comment: I really like this post, although I did find it a bit confusing when you said that $\max(0,1)$ and $\max(-1,0)$ are both $1$. Can you define a function $Q(x,y)=\max\{-x,y\}$ and instead say that $Q(0,1)$ and $Q(-1,0)$ are both $1$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer @MatthewPilling And your $Q$ function is what I meant.