# Is $\max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$ a one dimensional or two dimensional statistic?

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Is statistic $\max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$ one dimension or two dimension?

I was trying to find the minimal sufficient statistic for $U(-\theta,\theta)$ from $n$ $i.i.d$ random variables $X_i$. The result is that $\theta\ge \max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$ thus the minimal sufficient statistic is $\max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$. However, the problem actually states that "Find a **two dimensional** minimal sufficient statistic for $U(-\theta,\theta)$". Is $\max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$ a two dimensional statistic?

Here $X_{(i)}$ is the $i^{th}$ smallest value of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by $\{X_{(i)}\}$ you mean the *ordered* sequence constructed from $\{X_i\}$. The minimal sufficient statistics is the pair of $(min\{X_i\}, max\{X_i\})$, however, if the sequence is ordered, then you are right; the minimal sufficient statistics is $max\{-X_{(1)}, X_{(n)}\}$, but it requires an additional step of *ordering*.

**Correction**

Yes. You are right. $max\{|X_i|\}$ is the sufficient statistics.

Comment: I think the minimal sufficient statistic of $\theta$ using $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is $\max\{-X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\}$, not $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$.

Comment: If $\{X_i\}$ is already *increasingly ordered*, yes you are right. But if not, then you are going to have to find both min and max of the sequence, hence a pair.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973864/minimal-sufficient-statistics-for-uniform-distribution-on-theta-theta