# Find a comlete and sufficient statistics for $U(-\theta,\theta)$

Tags: probability

Find a comlete and sufficient statistics for $U(-\theta,\theta)$. I know that for $U(a,b)$ the complete and sufficient statistic is $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ but I'm not sure if for this one is just $X_{(n)}$

Comment: And what if your sample were $(-10, -7, 1, 3, 4)$?  Then $X_{(n)} = 4$, but this discards information in the sample that implies we must have $\theta \ge 10$.

Comment: If $X_i\sim U(-\theta,\theta)$, then $|X_i|\sim U(0,\theta)$.

Comment: So essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699997/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1973864/321264.